# Prioritize PPA/repos with the same host

Tags: 11.10, apt, package-management, ppa, repository

I'm using GIMP every day (on 11.10). Because of this, I need the Single-Window mode feature.

So, I've added the [matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn PPA](https://launchpad.net/~matthaeus123/+archive/mrw-gimp-svn), but as you see the description:

> GIMP 2.7.5 Will not work with the current glib and gtk in Oneiric. To
>   fix the problem install these repos
>
> ```
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu oneiric main
>
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu oneiric main
> ```

I had to install them. The Gnome3 repo is quite OK, but the Ricotz Testing is full of new unity and other not needed update.

As the result of the previous, **I'm experiencing some UI inconveniences**. (Eg. the backgrounds and the text colors of the indicators' menus are nearly the same - so hard to read them.)
(As it is shown there:)

> You are getting bleeding edge snapshots! You should have a stable
>   experience most of the time, but there will be problems!

I've googled around about repo prioritizing, and I've found the repo host pin option:

```
 Package: *
 Pin: origin "ftp.debian.org"
 Pin-Priority: 400
```

It is too much! I've other PPAs, whose are OK. I wanna just the bad one: [ricotz/testing](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing).

I've heard about [PPA-Purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge). So the downgrade won't be a problem. **I just wonder the prioritizing of the repos, OR other sources of GIMP Single-Window mode+Gnome Shell(3)**.

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you pin the ricotz/testing PPA at 1? Do you additionally need to pin the default repositories at a higher priority? If that is the case, do you need to pin the pertinent packages to install from ricotz/testing?

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question (not on Ubuntu right now), but on the build-depends in the DSCs for all the packages in the GIMP PPA, I can't find anything in terms of glib/gtk that isn't in the GNOME3 PPA. What happens if you remove ricotz/testing? (Or does "I had to install them" mean that you've already tried that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/04/install-gimp-28-rc1-from-ppa-ubuntu.html) site, there's a new ppa for gimp. Seems to be working fine, installation instructions are the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best answer to this problem is going to be "Upgrade to 12.04." If you want to install and use gnome-shell, and other newer applications, it's best to upgrade to the newer version of Ubuntu, which already has most everything you want. While the PPA is installable on Oneiric, it will break other default applications on the system, which are not designed to work with the newer versions, as they weren't part of Ubuntu at the time. If it's just the newer versions of glib and gtk+ which are necessary, then it's probably best if the PPA owner copied those packages to his PPA, rather than telling you to add other PPAs. How did he even get the package built in his PPA, if it requires newer versions which aren't in it? Sounds like the PPA and that gimp package is broken, as it apparently isn't depending on the newer versions.

As an alternative, you could create your own PPA on Launchpad, copy the glib/gtk+ packages in from the gnome3 PPA, then copy the gimp in from this PPA and have it rebuild against the new glib/gtk+ once they are in your PPA and published. Then simply add your own PPA and upgrade from there. You could also set up daily builds of the new GIMP trunk code, but that is a bit more involved.

Comment: The PPA he's getting GIMP from doesn't have anything for Precise.

Comment: Thank you, these are nearly good alternatives.As @zpletan wrote, there is no dev GIMB Precise packages available on that PPA. I'm planning to reinstall my laptop after Precise's release date+1 month. I wanna try it out first on other workplace. | Your second suggestion is seems to be better. I've some new questions about that:
(1)Can I copy/sync somehow the packages automatically the Glib from Rico Tzschichholz's PPA to my own PPA? Or it is better to do it every time when GIMP has an upg, manually?
(2)Can I upload DEB packages to my PPA, or I have to set up Launchpad to compile it from source?

Comment: zpletan: The GIMP 2.7.5 package is newer that what comes in Precise, so while it is not explicitly built on Precise, it might work. And it could be copied to another PPA and built on Precise, on Launchpad.

B.Roland (1) Launchpad has a "copy packages" feature for PPAs. You simply go to the page for the PPA you wish to copy packages from, and there is a "Copy packages" link. (2) You can't upload binary packages to a PPA. You have to upload a source package, which gets built in a clean chroot, to ensure it is properly duplicable.

Comment: Thank you, copying works, but I have to finish that work. I've no time now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way around this is to apt-get update.  Not do an apt-get upgrade.

Then apt-get install the gimp version you want, so it only pulls in the direct dependencies.

Then remove the ppas from the source list.

It should get you by another few weeks until 12.04 gets here.

Comment: Thank you, but: I'm planning to reinstall my laptop after Precise's release date+1 month. I wanna try it out first on other workplace, and wait a bit for fix the bigger bugs - as always.