# GIMP 2.7 without using PPA?

Tags: 11.10, gimp

I need to install Gimp 2.7 for obvious reasons when compared to 2.6., however the *ppa:matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn*  needs more PPA which do mess with my systems libraries.

Is there a safe way to install Gimp 2.7 (especially latest 2.7.5) without messing with system libs like glib?

Comment: You might see how the asker of http://askubuntu.com/q/112142/8724 is coming along. He has about the same problem, and the solution he finds will probably solve the root of your problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/04/install-gimp-28-rc1-from-ppa-ubuntu.html) site, there's a new ppa for gimp. Seems to be working fine, installation instructions are the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: I'm in slow connection and I cannot test it. Just added ppa and updated. I will try to upgrade current Gimp to 2.7 but I'm also thinking of waiting for Pangolin :)